# Unable to navigate using useNavigate() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here I'm trying to navigate to "/home" route using useNavigate() hook right after the login request is successful. Instead of routing to '/home', its reloading the "/login".
Here I'm attaching code

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([{
    path: '/',
    element: isUserValid() ? <Navigate to="/home" replace /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />,
    errorElement: <Error />
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    element: !isUserValid() ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/home" replace />
  }, {
    path: '/register',
    element: !isUserValid() ? <Register /> : <Navigate to="/home" replace />
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    element: isUserValid() ? <Form /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
  }])
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  )
}
```

In the above `isUserValid()`  returns true or false based on the session maintained in localStorage.

**Login.js**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        const isValid = onSubmit(e);
        if (isValid) {
            const payLoad = {};
            for (let key in formData) {
                payLoad[key] = formData[key]['value'];
            }
            try {
                const response = await login(payLoad);
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
                debugger;
                console.log("//== before navigation")
                navigate('/home', { replace: true });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("inside login error");
                setApiErrorMessage(err.response.data.error);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is for form submission, I'm able to get the token from the backend and able to store it in localStorage.

***Here is the problem occures, I'm unable to re route to '/home'. Please provide me a solution.***

Comment: when you put:   {
    path: '/home',
    element: <Navigate to="/home" replace />
  }])

can you get to "home"?

Comment: What is `isUserValid`? What does it do? When do you think it's called? As a hint it appears to be called only once when `App` renders and mounts the router and routes.

Answer (score 0):

Since setting to local storage is an asynchronous operation, navigation might be taking place before value is set to local storage and the `isUserValid` function might be returning false, hence redirecting to login.

Comment: AFAIK `localStorage` is actually a *synchronous* function and operation.